# swift3.0 project can't have .h file in any tags

Tags: ios, swift

my project created by swift3.0.and i had create `.h` file as bridge file.[image]

but this file `Target Menbership` can't edit,like:[image]

add this bridge file:
[image]

error:
[image]

what should I do??

Comment: The path to `Bridging-Header.h` is not correct, it must be `MyWidgetDemo/Bridging-Header.h`. Compare the "Full Path" in first photo and the error in the second photo.

Comment: Side note: "Target membership" is for files which are *compiled* as part of a target. Header files are *not* compiled, they are simply imported by other files which are compiled.

Comment: Just ask the question, I found that he had made a very low error.Thank you for your help very much!!!(OMG,I spent an hour in order to this problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the value of the build configuration `Objective-C Bridging Header` from `Bridging-Header.h` to `MyWidgetDemo/Bridging-Header.h`. This is where the file actually is. I could see that in your screenshot next to `Full Path`.

Comment: Just ask the question, I found that he had made a very low error.Thank you for your help very much!!!(OMG,I spent an hour in order to this problem)